# from address come with server extension in mail

Tags: php

from address come with server extension, errror info@gmail.com via ecbiz132.hostername.com . how to solve this
$subject           =    "confirmation";

$from             = "info@gmail.com";
$to           =  $email;

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

```
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

            $headers .= 'To:<'.$to.'>' . "\r\n";

            $headers .= 'From: <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";


            $senad_replay = mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers, $from);
```

// errror info@gmail.com  via ecbiz132.hostername.com . how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get rid the "via" part. Here's the details:

```
1) SPF and DKIM
```

Firstly, you would need to set an SPF record for the domain you are sending emails from and enable DKIM as well. These are primarily for identifying your messages against spam.

```
2) "From: anything@yourdomain.com"
```

Secondly, make sure you are setting the “From: ” header to be an email address on the domain you are sending messages from. Don’t pretend to be someone else. Use “From: someone@abc.com” if you are sending the messages from abc.com, rather than anything else, such as blah@def.com, or yours@gmail.com, or whatever. If you want the recipient to reply to your Gmail email instead of your domain email, use the “Reply-To: ” header. “From: ” must always be the domain email that you are sending the email from.

```
3) "Return-Path: return@yourdomain.com"
```

Thirdly and most importantly, set the “Return-Path: ” header to be the same domain as that of the “From: ” header. Use the 5th parameter of the mail() function for this:

```
mail('recipient@example.com', 'Subject', "Message Body", $headers, '-freturn@yourdomain.com')
```

So the Return-Path of this message would be “return@yourdomain.com” (the email address immediately following the -f switch). The $headers parameter should contain all the necessary message headers. Make sure “From: ” is something@yourdomain.com.

After these steps and measures, Gmail should now completely trust your messages from yourdomain.com. The ‘via‘ field of your messages should be gone and the ‘mailed-by‘ field as well as the ‘signed-by‘ field should be correctly showing up as yourdomain.com.

Hope it helps!

Comment: this one ok solved that prblm. but this time comes info@sitename.com to me, me